# TypeError: 'Engine' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```py
import pyttsx3 as pyt
import datetime as DT
hour = int(DT.datetime.now().hour)
print(hour)

# enter code here

speak = pyt.init()
voices = speak.getProperty('voices')
speak.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
    speak("Good Morning Sir !")
elif hour >=0 and hour<12 and hour<18:
    speak("Good Afternoon Sir !")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to call `speak.say` instead of just `speak` like such:

```py
if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
    speak.say("Good Morning Sir !")
elif hour >=0 and hour<12 and hour<18:
    speak.say("Good Afternoon Sir !")
```

And also, you should rename `speak` to `engine` to be more descriptive. Here's an example from [the docs](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#examples):

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```